# Vertically Center CSS ::after Content, with Float, in Parent DIV

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

How can I vertically center content, produced by an `::after` pseudo-element, inside of the parent element when the `::after` pseudo-element is applying a `float: right`?

I have the following CSS defined:

```
.label-dot::after, .label-dot-1::after {
  content: "";
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px; }

.label-dot-1::after {
  background-color: #66c2a5; }
```

... and apply it to the following (test case) HTML:

```
<div style="width: 500px; background-color: red;">
  <div class="label-dot-1">Neato</div>
</div>
```

A JSFiddle of the test code can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/EvilClosetMonkey/jR9sV/

Notice that the green dot on the right is aligned to the top, as well as the right, of the `div`. How can I get the dot to align itself with the vertical center of the `div`, like the text is?

**UPDATE**

Two additional pieces of info:

1. I do know the `height` of the parent `div`. I forgot I did when I posted my question. :)
2. I do not *need* to use `float`, but I do need the 'dot' aligned to the right (per comments below).

A new fiddle is here, with the height update: http://jsfiddle.net/EvilClosetMonkey/jR9sV/2/

Comment: Is it a requirement that the pseudo must have float..?

Comment: No, provided I can still stick the "dot" to the right margin (and I can't assume a width of the parent).

Comment: @TJ, I did just remember - I **do** know the `height` of the parent `div`, I just can't assume the `width`.

Comment: Do you actually need the child div `.label-dot-1` with unknown height or did you put it there just for creating the `pseudo`..? sice you're calling the first div `parent` i got confused.. anyway check the updated  answer and let me know..

Comment: @TJ, the parent will ultimately hold multiple children which may, or may not, be a `label-dot-*` class. All the children will inherit most of the sizing information, but will have a different color dot (or not dot at all).

Comment: So you want the dot to be vertically centered relative to `.label-dot-1`, right..? if yes, this is our parent element which still has an unknown height ;) check the updated answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By applying `position:relative` to the grand parent element with known height, we will then be able to absolutely position the `pseudo` relative to it, as follows:

```
#container {
 position:relative;
 height:20px;
 width: 500px;
 background-color: red;
}
.label-dot-1{

}
.label-dot-1::after {
 content:"";
 position:absolute;
 right:0;
 top:5px; /* (20px - 10px)/2 */
 border-radius: 50%;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 10px;
 width: 10px;
 background-color: #66c2a5;
}
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/jR9sV/3/)

**UPdate**

The following aligns the `pseudo` relative to it's parent with unknown height. It partially uses the [absolute centering technique](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/) for centering vertically, then relies upon css3 `calc()` function for the right alignment.

```
#container {
 width: 500px;
 background-color: red;
}
.label-dot-1{
 position:relative;
}
.label-dot-1::after {
 content:"";
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 right:0;
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
 margin:auto calc(100% - 10px);
 height: 10px;
 width: 10px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: #66c2a5;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/jR9sV/4/)

Comment: but he doesnt know what the hight of the parent is.. its variable it could be 10 but it could be 100

Comment: I actually do know the height of the pseudo element's parent, but not the container holding those (the pseudo-element's "grandparent" so-to-speak). The `top` worked well, but the `calc` (just learned about it) is awesome! Now I don't have to know the height and can reuse the class!!

Answer (score 1):

simple add

```
position:absolute; top:50%;
```

to `.label-dot-1::after` and then set the parent to be relatively positioned

http://jsfiddle.net/FquzF/ example

Comment: if `top:50%` then there the element won't be vertically centered unless it has 0px height, becuase below the element you need another 50% space for it to be in center...

Comment: et margin-top:-yy where yy is half the height of the child container to offset the item up.